# Showing that the limit of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+\frac{1}{2})^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{2}$ by taking a look at the result of a Fourier series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

What I found out: If we turn the function
$$f(x):=\begin{cases} \, 1 & 0 < x < \pi \\ 0 & x = 0 \\ -1 & -\pi < x < 0\end{cases}$$
into a Fourier series, we get the result (evaluated at $x = \pi/2$, I justify this by the pointwise convergence of the Fourier series at values $x >0$ to $1$)
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \enspace$$
This comes from the (simplified) Fourier series of f:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2\sin{[(2n+1)x]}}{(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi}$$
I found this problem: Using the result you find by turning f into its Fourier series, find the value of
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+\frac{1}{2})^2}$$
Spoiler Alert: using Maple I found that the above sum converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$. I am stuck on how to proceed, I tried to take the Cauchy product of the series with itself, only to notice I can't even do that because the series above is not absolutely convergent. I think I'm missing just one step, but I can't seem to find it. (Might I have to modify the function f above to say $x$ instead of $1$? I'll try that now but I don't think that is it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

If 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2\sin((2n+1)x)}{\pi(n+1/2)}$$
then
$$\int f(x)dx+C=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2\cos((2n+1)x)}{\pi(n+1/2)(2n+1)}$$

Comment: OMG this did the trick. Never would have thought to integrate that bad boi. Thanks!

Comment: @Christopher The fact that you just referred to an infinite series as a "bad boi"  increased my respect for you tenfold. XD

Comment: Hahaha I'll take it as a compliment!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Parseval's theorem. This states that if
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin(nx)$$
then 
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2 dx = \pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2.$$
Since you already know the $b_n$'s, all that remains is for you to evaluate the integral of $f^2$, and plug the $b_n$'s into the formula.

Comment: I don't get it. You mean my f from above? It always turns out 0, thus the pi's cancel. f is an odd function, f*f is even, so the integral should give 0, thus cancelling the pi's i would need. I know I missed something stupid, please help me out.

Comment: I don't think you really mean to say that the integral of an even function is always zero. Consider $\int_{-1}^1 1 dx$. :)  I assume that this was merely a brain-lapse.

Comment: Indeed it isn't. I should go to sleep.